# What's the simplest way to calculate a controls' inner display rectangle (with Padding subtracted)?

Tags: winforms, label

**A control reports its display rectangle in `.DisplayRectangle` -- what is the simplest way of finding the area available for the control if `.Padding` is set?**

For example, a `Label` has `.DisplayRectangle` always equal to `.ClientRectangle`, even if `.Padding` is not `(0,0,0,0)`. I want to obtain the size of the rectangle in `.ClientRectangle` after paying attention to the `.Padding` setting (and whatever additional properties might limit the "net" display area, for that matter).

Isn't there some method, or other framework-supported way to do it? Do I have to re-code all those rectangle calculations that probably are already in the framework code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Padding isn't simply a straight modification to Display Rectangle.  Some built-in controls factor it in, some do not.

Best is to read the documentation for Padding and see which parts apply to you.

The hopefully on-target simple answer is "No, there's no framework method.  Build your own like below"

```
private Rectangle GetPaddedRectangle(Control control)
{
    var rect = control.ClientRectangle;
    var pad = control.Padding;
    return new Rectangle( rect.X + pad.Left, 
                          rect.Y + pad.Top, 
                          rect.Width - (pad.Left+pad.Right), 
                          rect.Height - (pad.Top+pad.Bottom));
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That´s the point -- the dox are rather vague on some aspects of .Padding. One has to estimate which control uses .Padding in what way.